# How can I insert an image in a QMenu?

Tags: image, qt, qlabel, qmenu

I tried to make it like this :

```
QWidgetAction *labelAct = new QWidgetAction(screenMenu);
QLabel *label = new QLabel("sadas", screenMenu);
labelAct->setDefaultWidget(label);
screenMenu->addAction(labelAct);
```

but label is empty:

[image: empty label]

Answer (score 1):

you can use QLabel  [setPixmap()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#pixmap-prop) to set a pixmap

Something like:

```
QWidgetAction *labelAct = new QWidgetAction(screenMenu);
QLabel *label = new QLabel("sadas", screenMenu);
QPixmap mypix (":/test.png");
label->setPixmap(mypix);
labelAct->setDefaultWidget(label);
screenMenu->addAction(labelAct);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use just the [`void setIcon( const QIcon& icon )`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#icon-prop) function of the [`QAction`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html).

```
labelAct->setIcon( QIcon( "icon path" ) );
```

Comment: The size of the action's icon is small (16x16) - Qt 5.15.8 - `QWidgetAction` worked for me, Frédéric Da Silva's above.